# How can i solve this error "Cannot perform run time binding on a null reference" C#

Tags: c#

I have parsed a Json response:

```
string url = "http://words.bighugelabs.com/api/2/API KEY/" + word.ToString() + "/json";
```

and stored it in a string named sbb.
Then i stored the sbb in a dynamic object as it follows in order to retrieve a specific information of a given word, for example noun. Because it returns information about a single word each time.

```
dynamic foo = JObject.Parse(sbb);
var ant = foo.adjective.ant;
```

But after foo it doesn't always follow adjective it may be noun or something else, so when i try to see if var is null i have the error message. What can i do in order to check which case is null or not?
The 4 cases are:

```
foo.adjective.ant; foo.noun.ant; foo.adverb.ant; foo.verb.ant;
```

Comment: `if (foo.adjective != null)`?

Comment: works like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a defensive `null` check like

```
if(foo != null && foo.adjective != null)
```

If you are using C# 6 then you can as well use null propagation operator `?` like

```
if(foo?.adjective != null)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var ant = foo.adjective != null ? foo.adjective.ant :
          (foo.noun != null ? foo.noun.ant :
          (foo.adverb != null ? foo.adverb.ant :
          (foo.verb != null ? foo.verb.ant : null)));
```